# Display Joomla search results, one by one in each module?

Tags: search, module, joomla3.2

I am working on Joomla 3.2 with Roksprocket right now, which is a module that can display all articles in category X in "mosaic" form.  So you have blocks of intro articles instead of a list.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to display search results in "mosaic" form, or if I can somehow make the search results display one module at a time via Roksprocket.

Any pointers will help!

thanks,
V

Comment: Post a comment on the Rockettheme forums as this is a specific extension related issue

Comment: You should be able to achieve this with a template override, but it's up to you to integrate the roksprocket logic and style into it. Any joomla blog view will allow this kind of layout for categories.

Comment: @Lodder I did comment on Rockettheme forums but they don't give good replies.  They only say, no, its not possible and don't suggest any other ways I can try to make it possible.